# Prove that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$.

Tags: uniform-convergence

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ define the function $f_n : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f_n(x) = xe^{x/n}$, and define $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = x$. Prove that $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $[0, 1]$.

So far I have:

$f_n(x) = xe^{x/n} \le e^{1/n}$. I was thinking of $N = \lceil 1/\epsilon \rceil$ and then:

$|f_n(x) - f(x)| = |xe^{x/n} - x| \le e^{1/n} \le e^{1/N} < \epsilon$, but I don't think $e^{1/N} < \epsilon$ is true. I have an exceedingly tough time choosing $N$ every time I have to prove one of these.

Not sure if I approached this correctly.

Comment: $e^{1/N}>1$ for all $N \in \Bbb{N}$, so this inequality would fail for any $\varepsilon \leq 1$

Comment: Actually, if I assume $e^{1/n} < \epsilon$, then $n < 1/\ln(\epsilon)$, so can I make $N = 1/\ln(\epsilon)$

Comment: But if $\varepsilon = 1$ then you'd be dividing by zero. And if $\varepsilon < 1$ that would make $N$ negative.

Comment: @graydad then does that mean there is no way to choose an N, and hence it does not converge uniformly?

Comment: @David Please tell us how you obtain the inequality $|xe^{x/n}-x|\le e^{1/n}.

Comment: No I believe this function converges uniformly, which means there is a way to choose $N$. I suspect there is something more that can be done with the inequalities to make the answer pop out. I'll play around with it and see what I can figure out. user37238 has asked about the inequality I have been trying to figure out.

Comment: Ah, copper.hat has figured out what you need. You want to choose $N > \frac{1}{\ln(1+\varepsilon)}$

Comment: Ah, so my computation was almost there. I just needed to get rid of the edge case.

Comment: You were missing a "minus one" in the inequality after you drop the absolute value. You need that when you choose your $N$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$|f(x)-f_n(x)| = |x||e^{x \over n}-1| \le e^{1 \over n}-1$.